# Assembly program not displaying or looping before returning control

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have this program that should return the inverse of a character or characters eg A -> Z, B -> Y etc. The code works and properly converts the character but the program doesn't display it on screen or loop when it should, instead, it returns control at `int 21h`.

```
.8086
.model small
.data
    
    ; Variables
    prompt_in db 0Dh, "Input: $"
    prompt_out db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Output: $"


.code
   main proc
    
    ; Load Variables
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    ; Display Input Prompt
    mov dx, offset prompt_in
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    
    mov cl, 00
    mov ah, 01h
    
    ; Read input and push to BX until User presses Return (Enter)
    read:
        int 21h
        mov bl, al
        push bx
        inc cx
        
        cmp al, 0Dh
        jz return
        
        jmp read
    
    ; Display Output Prompt    
    return:
        mov dx, offset prompt_out
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
    
    ; Calculate Inverse Letter and Display      
    calc:
    
        mov ah, 00
        pop bx
        
        cmp bl, 0Dh
        jz calc
        
        mov al, bl
        sub al, 41h
        mov cl, 19h
        mov ch, 2
        mul ch
        sub cl, al
        add bl, cl
        
        mov dl, bl
        int 21h ; Stops Code Here without Displaying anything more
        loop calc ; Doesn't Loop Here
               
    
        mov ah, 4Ch
        int 21H
    main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOS service to write a character to standard output is [`int 21h` with `ah = 02h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm).  But that's not what you are doing:

- Just after the `calc` label you load `ah` with the value `00`, not `02h`.
- A few lines later, you have a `mul ch` instruction.  Remember that `mul` on x86 is widening; an 8-bit multiply produces a 16-bit result in `ax`, which in particular overwrites `ah`.  Now in your program, the result will probably fit in 8 bits, so that `ah` is set to zero again.

When you call `int 21h` with `ah = 0`, you invoke the [terminate program service](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) (a deprecated predecessor to `int 21h / ah = 4Ch`), which is why your program terminates at this point.

The quick solution is to insert `mov ah, 02h` just before the `int 21h`, and remove the earlier `mov ah, 00` which is wrong and also redundant.

You can improve the program further by noticing that multiplication by 2 is the same as a left shift by 1, which is faster and doesn't involve so many registers.  It won't be quite the same if the result overflows 8 bits (the high part of the result is lost, instead of being put in `ah`) but you don't expect to handle that case anyway.  So your `mov ch, 2 / mul ch` can be replaced with simply `shl al, 1`.  This moreover doesn't touch `ah` at all.

Comment: Actually there's `mul ch` between the two instructions you quoted. And that does change `ah`. It's just likely to also set `ah` to zero, resulting in the same service call.

Answer (score 1):

[Nate Eldredge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618068/3144770) thoroughly explained why your program exits early before even displaying any output. I hope that you've corrected this by now. Then you will have seen that **the program crashes**!

1. You're complicating matters. The task to convert A-Z into Z-A is a simple one that does not involve multiplication nor shifting.

   ```
   sub al, "A"
   sub al, "Z"-"A"
   neg al
   add al, "A"
   ```

   Even shorter:

   ```
   sub al, "A"
   neg al
   add al, "Z"
   ```
2. The program will loop forever and eventually crash because you're using the `LOOP` instruction that depends on the `CX` register and your code is reloading this counter register with a big non-zero value.

   ```
    mov ch, 2      <-- reloads with value 512+
    ...
    loop calc      <-- jumps forever
   ```

---

This will work:

```
    pop  dx     ; First pop is the carriage return for sure!
                ; Why do you even push it in the first place?
calc:
    pop  dx
    sub  dl, "A"
    neg  dl
    add  dl, "Z"
    mov  ah, 02h  ; DOS.PrintCharacter
    int  21h
    loop calc
```

Please note that, at the start of the input, you should zero the whole `CX` register and not just write `mov cl,0`. It's a bad habit to rely on the particular behaviour (about zeroed registers) of the emulator that you're using.